# invalid number oracle sql on datetime add

Tags: sql, oracle

I believe there is some bad data in some of the rows in this table. I'm getting invalid number when I try something like this... other tables don't cause an issue.

Is there someway I can prevent the query from failing?

```
where to_char(t1.create_date) 
between to_char(t2.create_date - INTERVAL '10' MINUTE) and
to_char(t2.create_date + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE)
```

Comment: Remove all the `to_char`s and it might work!

Comment: I'm gonna try that again, the query has a fairly lengthy run time. I actually had the invalid number error occur before I added the to_chars. That was before I changed to the internal '10' MINUTE from +.0x for the minutes though. Fingers crossed?

Comment: Are you doing an implicit or explicit conversion of a string to a number in the select list, or a join, or elsewhere in the where clause? How have you established it's the interval calculation that's throwing that exception?

Comment: No, just this. This was actually an already established query but I had to modify due to a business process change. So I'm fairly confident it's just this select/where statement. This is a subquery within a larger query..... Wow... as I'm typing this I just realized that the subquery returns a varchar now where previously I was using a number... duh... thanks! I'm going to try this again.

Comment: You can also write `10 * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE`

Comment: @AlexPoole .. sorry for the delay.. your comment made realize the mistake in my query. It has nothing to do with the datetime (I always seem to have issues, so it's the first place I work). I was able to resolve and the query runs fine. Thank you! If you want to post an answer I will vote it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
where t1.create_date
between (t2.create_date - 10/1440) and (t2.create_date + 10/1440)
```

Comment: The intervals aren't causing the problem. The OP mentioned in a comment that they had `+ 0.x` before changing to intervals, which is the same thing you're doing really. It doesn't seem to be anything to do with the code shown in the question.